# Why I cannot verify my own chain of certificate

Tags: certificate, openssl

I have created 3 certificate

- root.pem: Self signed root CA
- intermediate.pem: An Intermediate CA signed by the root CA
- user.pem: A user cert signed by Intermediate CA

I would like to verify the chain is ok by issuing this command:

`openssl verify -CAfile root.pem -untrusted intermediate.pem user.pem`

But I get:

```
user.pem: C = US, ST = Virginia, L = Dulles, O = Corp., OU = TEST, CN = User Cert
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

This However works:

`openssl verify -CAfile root.pem intermediate.pem`
intermediate.pem: OK

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer my own question:

I created the Intermediate CA certificate wrongly, when creating the cert from the CSR I did not put in the -extfile the right configuration (it was missing CA:TRUE and the certSign flag)

After recreating the Intermediate and User cert the command showed 'OK'